# Не выводится элемент в Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Здравствуйте!

Кто знаком со Smarty? Помогите пожалуйста! Есть список постов и комменты к ним. Если в возвращаемом массиве комментов есть комментарий к посту, то он выводится, а если нет, то выводится форма добавления комментария. Комментарии выводятся, а вот там где нет комментария по идее должна отображаться форма, но почему-то не срабатывает.

```
{foreach $products as $item}

    <h2><a href="/product/page/{$item['id']}/">{$item['title']}</a></h2>
    {foreach $comments as $comment}
        {if $comment['post_id'] == $item['id']}
            <p>{$comment['content']}</p>
        {/if}
    {foreachelse}

                <div id="blockNewComment">
                    <form 
                       ...
                    </form>
                </div>

    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так получается, поскольку условие `foreachelse` здесь не корректно. Оно ведь сработает, только в том случае, когда у вас вообще пустой массив `comments`, а вы хотите узнать, есть ли комменты  для данного продукта (с нужным `comment['post_id']`).
Вообще основная проблема тут в том, что вы на уровне представления пытаетесь решать задачи логики, это не совсем корректно. По хорошему в пхп-коде должны извлечь продукты и комменты к ним, так чтобы каждый продукт имел свои комментарии `$item.comments`. Поэтому тут два пути, лучшим будет на уровне логики сначала распихать комментарии куда надо, а потом выводить. Второй вариант, использовать другие проверки вместо`foreachelse`.

Первый примерно так:

Сначала подготавливаете данные

```
$products = getAllProducts(); 
$comments = getComment($userID);
$model = [];
foreach($products as $p){
     $pid = $p['id'];
     $model[$pid] = $p;
     foreach($comments as $idx => $c){
        if($c['post_id'] != $pid) continue;
        $model[$pid']['comments'][] = $c;
     }
}
$smarty->assign('model', $model);
```

и выводите (проверок на соответствие id уже нет):

```
{foreach $model as $p}    
    <h2>{$p.title}</h2>
    {foreach $p.comments as $c}
        <p>{$c.content}</p>
    {foreachelse}
         .....
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Второй вариант - модифицировать ваше представление следующим образом, добавив переменную `$hasComments`

```
{foreach $products as $item}
    <h2><a href="/product/page/{$item['id']}/">{$item['title']}</a></h2>

    {$hasComments = 0} 
    {foreach $comments as $comment}
        {if $comment['post_id'] == $item['id']}
            <p>{$comment['content']}</p>
            {$hasComments++} 
        {/if}
    {/foreach}

    {if !$hasComments}
        <div id="blockNewComment">
            <form 
                ...
            </form>
        </div>
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Класс! Спасибо большое! Еще две бесценных крупинки в базу моих знаний.

Answer (score 2):

`$comments` это что? элемент `$item`? Тогда надо так:

```
{foreach $products as $item}
    {foreach $item.comments as $comment}
        {if $comment['post_id'] == $item['id']}
            <p>{$comment['content']}</p>
        {/if}
    {foreachelse}
        ...
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: $comments это такой же массив данных как $products,
Вот из контроллера код:

$products = getAllProducts();

    $userID = isset($_SESSION['user']) ? $_SESSION['user']['id'] : null;

    $comments = getComment($userID);

    $smarty->assign('pageTitle', '');
    $smarty->assign('products', $products);
    $smarty->assign('comment', $comment);